# Shopify ajax api adding the wrong number of items

Tags: shopify

You can check out the test store I've set up at http://pagac-group2595.myshopify.com/collections/monday (login with the pass 'euthuy')

We're trying to use the ajax api with the directions here (http://wiki.shopify.com/Ajax_API#You.27re_building_a_quick_order_form.3F_Beware) to $.post() things.

If you pull up your console, add a few products (almost all products on the page are $2.50, for reference) and use the grey 'click to submit' button in the top right of the page, you can see I'm logging out all the fields and they appear to be correct but when I get the xhr request back, I'm not seeing what I thought I put in. Even when leaving items blank, there always seems to be at least 1 birthday package, 2 mooberry, 2 monday migraine, and at least one of everything else. (I never thought I'd complain about too many cupcakes.)

When you evaluate $('input[data-title="Mooberry"]').val(); from the console, you'll get the intended value (whatever is in the form field) but when I submit it, I get a response saying I submitted quantity of 2.

I'm not really sure what I'm doing wrong here, the data seems to be going in nicely via js but the responses I'm getting aren't what I think I'm putting in.

Thanks much,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what the root issue was here but I resolved it by adding a condition where it checked for an quantity greater than zero.

```
Shopify.queue = [];

jQuery('.quantity-field').each(function() {
    var quantity = parseInt(jQuery(this).val(), 10);
    //make sure that more than 0 items are requested
    if (quantity > 0) {
        Shopify.queue.push({
            variant_id: jQuery(this).attr('data-variant'),
            quantity_amount: quantity,
            cupcake_title: jQuery(this).attr('data-title')
        });
    }
});
```

Regardless, I'd be curious to know why adding 0-quantity of an item to the cart makes it go into the cart at all. This functionality is reproducible if you simple do the following in console:

```
Shopify.add(a_valid_variant_id, 0, foo);
```

Then examine the response from `Shopify.cart();`

Is this a bug on Shopify's end?

Comment: Indeed that is the behaviour! Good eye.